# How to retrieve hidden folders using java?

Tags: java

```
public void Process(File aFile) throws IOException, ParseException {

  if(aFile.isFile())
  {
    System.out.println("File name:"+aFile.getAbsolutePath());
  }
  else if (aFile.isDirectory()) {

    File[] listOfFiles = aFile.listFiles((FileFilter) HiddenFileFilter.HIDDEN);
    if(listOfFiles!=null) {
          for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
              Process(listOfFiles[i]);
    } 

    File[] listOfFiles1 = aFile.listFiles((FileFilter) HiddenFileFilter.VISIBLE);
    if(listOfFiles1!=null) {
          for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles1.length; i++)
              Process(listOfFiles1[i]);
    } 
  }
}
```

Call the function in main as follows

```
String nam = "E:\\";
File aFile = new File(nam);
Process(aFile);
```

I am using the above code to retrieve all the file details which is present in E:\. It does not retrieve the hidden folder file details. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: When you said *It does not retrieve the hidden folder file details* does it means `listOfFiles` is null or that `Process` method do not process anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `aFile.listFiles()` without any `FileFilter` then put path of each hidden folder in a list based on check on `isHidden()`.

Sample code:

```
public static void process(File aFile){
    if (aFile.isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File name:" + aFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } else if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
        if(aFile.isHidden()){
            System.out.println(aFile.getAbsolutePath()+"folder is hidden");
        }
        File[] listOfFiles = aFile.listFiles();
        if (listOfFiles != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
                process(listOfFiles[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The folders are access denied. How to access those folders

Comment: Is it external drive? It's working fine for me. Try with `aFile.canRead()`

Comment: It retrieved all the folders but it does not retrieve the file details of the restricted folders

Comment: create new hidden and visible folders and then test it again for small set of folders instead of whole drive. If still there is issue with new folders as well then share the exception logs as well

Comment: After adding the permission in the folder properties, i can access the file details using the above code Thanks!!!!